# Getting a return value from Antlr Listener?

Tags: antlr, return-value, void, antlr4

i have a Antlr generated Listener, and i call my tree walker to go through the tree from a parse function in another class. Looks like this:

```
public double calculate(){

     ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("5+2");
     Lexer lexer = new Lexer(input);
     CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
     Parser parser = new Parser(tokens);
     ParseTree tree = parser.calculate();
     ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
     walker.walk(new Listener(), tree);
     return 0;
}
```

So the listener works perfect with the enter() and quit() Functions and prints the correct value in the end:

```
public void exitParser(ParserContext ctx) {
    result = stack.peek();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

But i wanna receive the final value in my calculate() function to return it there. Since exitParser(...) is void i dont know how to deal with it.

With the visitor i was able to do it like that:

```
public double calculate(){
    // ...
    String value = new WRBVisitor().visit(tree);
    return Double.parseDouble(value);
}
```

Hope someone understands my problem and knows a solution for it.

Best regards

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: So i call my listener and tree walker. And i want to get a return value. But all the listener functions are void. So how can i call my listener to get a return in my main function. Like:     String myReturnValue = walker.walk(new WRBListener(), tree);     thats sadly not possible. With the Visitor i can do:     String test = new WRBVisitor().visit(tree);     . Since im using the listener now, i wanna do the same. So all in all: I wanna return the calculated value to the calculate() function.

Comment: Drop listeners altogether. Visitors are much better for this task. Just create a visitor based on `YourGrammarBaseVisitor<Double>` and perform your calculations inside it.

Comment: Allright, i'll try that that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: a visitor might be a better option in your case. A visitor's methods will always return a value, which is what you seem to be after. That could be a `Double` if your expressions always evaluate to a numeric value, or some sort of *home-grown* `Value` that could represent a `Double`, `Boolean`, etc.

Have a look at my demo expression evaluator (using a visitor) on GitHub: https://github.com/bkiers/Mu